# The performance of an laptop can be affected by the battery and by the AC power adapter?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-supply, battery, dell-inspiron

I have a laptop Dell Inspiron 5567 (Windows 10) and today when I open the laptop I receive that message: "Alert! The AC power adapter wattage and type cannot be determined. The battery may not charge. The system will adjust the performance to match the power available."

Until this day, the laptop started fast and every applications started fast. And the battery is charging. Now the battery not charge and the laptop and applications started slowly.

#### So, I have this questions:

1. The battery should be change?
2. The AC power adapter should be change?
3. The laptop performance is affected by the battery or/and the AC power adapter? And how can be fixed?
4. If I change the battery or/and AC power adapter the performance laptop will increase (as when the laptop was new)?

**Note 1:** I looked for similar question and I not found something useful.
**Note 2:** If you need another information about the laptop, write back.

Comment: Most OEM mobile products have circuitry to identify OEM batteries.  If the circuit on the device or the battery fail what you describe would happen. You don't indicate how old the device is or how old the battery is.  *Laptop batteries do not last forever.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/104023/dell-inspiron-6400-indicates-the-wrong-power-adapter-is-plugged-in-and-will-not?rq=1) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/495501/dell-inspiron-n5010-has-failed-to-recognize-ac-adapter?rq=1)

Comment: The battery is four years old (like the laptop).

Comment: The Dell BIOS makes the system slower when the AC power type is not determined. As I experienced myself, and as it's written in the message you posted "The system will adjust the performance..." so you had your answer in the Dell message itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. The battery should be changed?   How old is the laptop?  After about 3 years the battery should be replaced in most instances
2. The AC power adapter should be changed?  Only if not working. Shut the computer down, start up on battery, plug in the charger and see if the battery indicator shows the AC connection. If so, leave it for an hour and see if the charge increases for the battery
3. The laptop performance is affected by the battery or/and the AC power adapter? And how can be fixed?  No, not normally. Only if the battery is too old to accept a good charge. This was your first question.
4. If I change the battery or/and AC power adapter the performance laptop will increase (as when the laptop was new)?

As noted earlier, the AC charger should probably be fine. Check as I suggested.

A new battery (OEM from Dell) works if the old battery will not keep a charge. How old is it?

Comment: You can start by resetting the Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery in Device Manager. Right-click on it, disable it, leave Device Manager open, go to services.msc with the Run box, find a service named CmBatt.svc, make sure it's stopped, or stop it manually (leave the console open), then go back to Device Manager, right-click on the Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery line, enable it again, check if the service has started (if not, start it manually), and see if you've still got that warning. The CmBatt.svc service should be set on "Auto" in terms of Start type.

Comment: If you can't find it in services.msc (the services are identified by their common name, not their codename, sometimes), try in Task Manager under Services.

Comment: The battery is four years old (like the laptop).

Comment: That is your issue. Time to replace the battery. The charger is likely OK because it will not charge a bad (old) battery

Comment: This kind of message has nothing to do with the battery, according to Dell.